# How to compare mongodb Object ids?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

To compare two mongo document ids I'm using the following query in nodejs.

```
  _id: { $gt: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(another_id) }
```

But what I need is initially I want to retrieve all the records from the collection. For that what should I pass it to another_id. For example, initially I tried passing null, "", and 0 .
query would look like below,

```
 _id: { $gt: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(null) }
 _id: { $gt: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("") }
```

But these fails. Can you please suggest me, what should I pass initially in another_id to retrieve all the records in the collection.

I'm trying to assign it to a variable and attaching it to query as below, but it is not working. Please suggest.

```
    let pagqy = {};
    if(bookmrk !== 0){
        pagqy = {_id: { $gt: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(bookmrk)}}  
    }
     if (fromdate == "" && todate == "") 
            query = { Class: param,pagqy } 
     else
          query = { E_Assigned_Date: { $gte: fromdate, $lte: todate }, Class: param,pagqy }
```

Comment: If you want to retrieve *all* records from the collection, do not specify any filtering criteria at all, e.g. pass `{}` to the query instead of `{_id: ...}`

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti I have updated the question. Please check and Kindly suggest me what should i do.

Comment: Is this an issue with the `Class` argument and the `query` object?   Does `query` expect more than one arg?    This is more of a `node.js` question than a `mongo` question.

Answer (score 0):

use this query to compare mongo _id

```
_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(another_id)
```

Comment: I want to retrieve ids greater than another id , thats why Im trying to write that.